# how to draw an arrow between two points on the map? MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

How to draw an arrow between two points on the map?

I try calculate latitude and longitude, but something goes wrong.

Best regards, Max

---

This is my code and result picture

**Code:**.

```
int currpoints1 = 2;
NSLog(@"numPoints = %d ",numPoints);
while(currpoints1 < numPoints)
{
    
    TrackPoint* current = nil;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D* coordsArrrow = malloc((3) * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    for (int i =currpoints1, j=0; i < numPoints; i=i+1, j++)
    {
        current = [cashpoints objectAtIndex:i];
        coordsArrrow[j] = current.coordinate;
        if (i % 2 !=0) {
            int Gug = 30;
            
            int ug;
            float bx, by, ex, ey;
            bx = coordsArrrow[0].latitude;by = coordsArrrow[0].longitude;
            ex = coordsArrrow[1].latitude;ey = coordsArrrow[1].longitude;
            float Lstr = sqrt((ex-ey)*(ex-ey)+(bx-by)*(bx-by));
            ug = [self RetGradW:(abs(coordsArrrow[1].latitude-coordsArrrow[0].latitude)) height:abs(coordsArrrow[1].longitude-coordsArrrow[0].longitude)];
            ug = ug - Gug;
            coordsArrrow[0].latitude  = ex;
            coordsArrrow[0].longitude = ey;
            coordsArrrow[1].latitude  = ex+Lstr*cos(ug*M_PI/180);
            coordsArrrow[1].longitude = ey+Lstr*sin(ug*M_PI/180);
            ug=ug+2*Gug;
            coordsArrrow[2].latitude  = ex+Lstr*cos(ug*M_PI/180);
            coordsArrrow[2].longitude = ey+Lstr*sin(ug*M_PI/180);
            
            MKPolyline *points = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordsArrrow count:3];
            points.subtitle = @"arrow";
            [map addOverlay:points];
            break;
        }
    }
    free(coordsArrrow);
    currpoints1 = currpoints1 +14;
}
```

**Picture:**

[image]

Comment: Put some stuff which U have been tried so far ..?

Comment: I want to show the direction on route. Maybe it is better to draw the annotation? and rotate annotation.

Comment: :) good looking now your question.

Comment: @KumarKl, I'm add my work.

Answer (score 1):

I changed it other way. Make annotation and rotate with direction between two point.

metods :

`calculateDirection`:

```
int currpoints1 = 2;
NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!%d ",numPoints);
while(currpoints1 < numPoints)
{
    TrackPoint* current = nil;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D* coordsArrrow = malloc((2) * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    for (int i =currpoints1, j=0; i < numPoints; i=i+1, j++) {
        current = [cashpoints objectAtIndex:i];
        coordsArrrow[j] = current.coordinate;
        if (i % 2 !=0) {
            DirectAnnotation *placemark=[[DirectAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: coordsArrrow[0]];
            
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = coordsArrrow[0];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = coordsArrrow[1];
            
            CLLocationDegrees deltaLong = coord2.longitude - coord1.longitude;
            CLLocationDegrees yComponent = sin(deltaLong) * cos(coord2.latitude);
            CLLocationDegrees xComponent = (cos(coord1.latitude) * sin(coord2.latitude)) - (sin(coord1.latitude) * cos(coord2.latitude) * cos(deltaLong));
            
            CLLocationDegrees radians = atan2(yComponent, xComponent);
            CLLocationDegrees degrees = radiansToDegrees(radians) + 360;
            
            self.dir =  fmod(degrees, 360);
            
            NSLog(@"%f,%f %f,%f",coordsArrrow[0].latitude,coordsArrrow[0].longitude,coordsArrrow[1].latitude,coordsArrrow[1].longitude);
            [self.map addAnnotation:placemark];
            break;
        }
    }
    free(coordsArrrow);
    currpoints1 = currpoints1 +14;
}
```

and

`annotation`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[DirectAnnotation class]]) {
        arrow=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"parkingloc"];
        arrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userLocationCompass.png"];
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(dir));
        arrow.transform = transform;
        return arrow;
    }else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

*But I am still facing some problems,*

**Before zoom:**

[image]

---

**After zoom:**

[image]

Direction is off.

Comment: In `viewForAnnotation`, it uses the `dir` variable which looks like it is not part of the DirectAnnotation class (ie. it's not in _each_ annotation).  I suggest making it part of the DirectAnnotation class instead of using the same variable across all annotations.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291201/problems-with-mapview-pin-annotation-pin-loses-color-when-map-is-zoomed-panned/13291738#13291738 for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrows change the angle because you don't reuse them in viewForAnnotation correctly.

Just make some unique id for each arrow like this in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
routeAnnotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[lmapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f",annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude]];

if (!routeAnnotationView)
{
    routeAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f",annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude]];
    UIImage *image = [self rotateImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrpix11.png"] onDegrees:RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(curAngle)+90];
    routeAnnotationView.image = image;
}
else
{
    routeAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;
}
routeAnnotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
```